# Is it acceptable to say “It is one of my most important things.”?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

My question is if I want to say

> It is one of the most important things for me.

In another way, can I say

> It is one of my most important things.

instead? And does the latter one sound strange to native speakers?

Comment: "My things" implies possession. World peace might be important *to* you, but that doesn't mean it's *yours*.

Comment: I would also use "to me" in the first, but prefer the second if it is something that belongs to you

Comment: I am wondering OP if you might be French and are looking for a translation of 'quelquechose d'importance chez moi'. I agree with mplungian above that 'to me' would be better. Sadly we have no equivalent of 'chez' in English, which is one French word that I love.

Answer (score 2):

"Things" as an abstract noun (or pseudo pronoun) needs a context which can't be created just by appending "my". “It is one of the most important things for me” implies by default "concerning my happiness or ability to cope" but would most likely be used in reference to an antecedent (previously mentioned) condition; as in: "When I'm studying, I like having a sharpened pencil at hand. It is one of the most important things for me.”

Whereas with “It is one of my most important things”, "my. . .things" would seem to to point to a concrete object; it might be said for instance by a lame person of a cane or crutch.

A colloquial American usage of "thing", often pronounced "thang", references habits rather than objects. If that were your intent it *might* sound okay to say: "Going to concerts- that's one of my *main things.* "Main" being the adjective normally used in place of "most important" for such a usage.

At any rate,"importance" is generally considered to be a relative evaluation, one that can't be made for others. By constructing the sentence as ". . .*my* most important things” it is left unclear whether one is stating a personal valuation or proclaiming particular ownership of a thing of universal importance; thus “It is one of my most important things”,
tends to seem awkward if not presumptive. (Presumption is a grievous error in mannerly English converse)